# WPF ComboBoxItem DataTemplate can't click item text to select

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm populating a `ComboBox` with an `ItemsSource` and showing a simple `Binding`:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Location}"
>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I can't choose a new combobox item by clicking the text (I have to click outside of the text):

[image]

So, if I click the darker blue area inside the inner border (the text container), it doesn't update the selection.  If I click in the lighter blue area, it updates as expected. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a ComboBoxItem in the ItemTemplate (because it is used as the ContentTemplate of another, automatically generated ComboBoxItem).

Use a TextBlock instead:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or just drop the entire ItemTemplate and just set DisplayMemberPath:

```
<ComboBox 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Location}"/>
```

Comment: Aha that works! Thank you. I'll go with `<TextBlock>` since I have some triggers in there.